# Java: converting string to specific locale

Tags: java, locale

I need to convert a string formatted with a certain locale, to a locale that i want. 
I receive string like:

0.00

123,133.07

3,700.36

Now, i would parse that string to float without decimal part, and replace "," separator with ".", Expected results should be like

0

123.133

3.700

This is my code:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ITALY);
Number number = format.parse(myStringUnformatted);
return number.floatValue();
```

But with this method i obtain

0 (correct)

123.133 (correct)

3.7 (wrong)

How can i do?

Comment: Can I clarify that you want to parse US format and output as Italian format? In which case the code you have is doing it the wrong way round. You are parsing the numbers as Italian and outputting them as US. In which case 3,700.36 is correctly being parsed as 3.7 and then there is a 36 after a period which isn't part of this number. The 123,133.07 you are printing out is converting 123133.07 to 123.133 and again ignoring the 07 after the period because it's not part of the number.

Answer (score 1):

[According to this document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html) you are misunderstanding the Italian number format. While in the US, a comma is a thousands grouper and a period is a decimal points separator, in most European countries it's the exact opposite.

For the output you need, the input should be

```
0,00
123.133,07
3.700,36
```

My guess is that your input numbers are not actually italian.

Comment: My input is not italian, i know. I receive input from a webservice, and i need to convert it as i've described

Answer (score 1):

You need to separate between the internal representation of the number, and the textual representation.

First, you get a textual representation of a number, on some format. You then parse this number into an internal representation. For this, you need to supply the format rules of the textual representation. From what I can tell, your input is not with italian format, since they use comma for decimals. Thus, your number is not parsed correctly. Once parsed, your number will have an internal representation, which in turn can be tuned to a certain locale when printed.

Also, I see nothing in your code that would actually remove any decimals.

The code should be something like this:

```
//input is in US format
final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
final Number number = format.parse("123,133.07");

//To print the number in Italian format, without decimals (gets rounded off though)
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.ITALY, "%.0f", number));

//To return rounded number
return Math.round(number.doubleValue());

//To return number without the decimals
return number.longValue();
```

Note that the Italian formatting of numbers does not include `.` as a thousands separator.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you aren't making a mistake in formatting the strings?

I just tried this:

```
public class numberformat {

    public static float parse(String numberString) throws ParseException {
        NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ITALY);
        Number number = format.parse(numberString);
        return number.floatValue();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
        System.out.println(parse("0"));
        System.out.println(parse("123.123,07"));
        System.out.println(parse("3.700,36"));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And got the following outputs:

```
0.0
123123.07
3700.36
```

Which seems to be what you'd expect.

Comment: the input you have used in your answer are not the input i have :)

Comment: I've edited the code in my IDE and came up with the expected results will modify answer accordingly.

Comment: Oh wait! I see what you are doing! You want to parse US format and output Italian format? In which case You can do as @Tobb suggests and use String.format to get it to print in the correct format once you've parsed it using the input format as above
System.out.println(String.format(Locale.ITALY, "%.0f", number));